# How to get auto-generate class from JSON object string using python

Tags: python, json, class

Like Visual Studio has an extension to auto-generate c# class file from JSON. Can we do the same in python using any tools?

That is, from:

```
{
    "person": {
       "firstName": "David,
       "lastName": "Daimer",
       "email": "d@gmail.com",
       "country": "United States",
     }
 }
```

to:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.first = data['firstName']
        self.last = data['lastName']
        self.email = data['email']
        self.country = data['country']
```

Comment: If you're talking about generating the file itself which you then add to your repository, anything from simple [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) to more robust [template rendering](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/) could be used to create a Python file based on those values.